# How to turn off automatic selection "wrapping" in PHP NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

Say I've got the following line of code and I'm editing it in NetBeans:

```
$foo = new Bar;
```

Then I decide I want to replace 'new Bar' with a string instead. So I select |new Bar| with my mouse and then type the " key. Instead of getting:

```
$foo = ";
```

I instead get:

```
$foo = "new Bar";
```

I find this quite annoying and it does the same thing for the ', {, (, {, and / keys, and probably others as well.

How can I turn this off?  I can't find an obvious setting for it in NetBeans 7.0.1 Preferences.

Comment: I love that feature! Why not press backspace + "?

Comment: @Shef I agree with you, but you can't ignore its really stepping in the way. I understand why people want to disable it.

Comment: @Shef Because most other text manipulation on a computer (other editors, word processors, webforms etc) would replace the highlighted text. You shouldn't break common UX patterns without good reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Options** - **Editor** - **Code Completion** - Disable **Insert Closing Brackets Automatically**

This also disables immediately entering closing quotes and brackets which you may not have wished for in the first place.

Frankly, it doesn't bother me at all. I remember finding it a bit annoying when I just started using netbeans, but I taught myself pressing delete or backspace every time I want to replace my selection with a character that could otherwise surround it. (And when I actually do want to quote or parenthesise a selection, I find this behaviour coming in quite handy.)

Comment: ...but I like the fact that it inserts closing braces. It's too bad this is combined into the same setting. I'll have to post a feature request about that. Thanks for the answer!